# Why can't I assign a value to LiveData?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I'm learning the LiveData, the *Code A* is from  https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-databinding

I think the *code A* is too complex, so I try to reduce it to *Code B*.

But the *Code B* can't be compiled, you can see *Image C*, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
class SimpleViewModelSolution : ViewModel() {
    private val _name = MutableLiveData("Ada")
    private val _lastName = MutableLiveData("Lovelace")
    private val _likes =  MutableLiveData(0)

    val name: LiveData<String> = _name
    val lastName: LiveData<String> = _lastName
    val likes: LiveData<Int> = _likes

    // popularity is exposed as LiveData using a Transformation instead of a @Bindable property.
    val popularity: LiveData<Popularity> = Transformations.map(_likes) {
        when {
            it > 9 -> Popularity.STAR
            it > 4 -> Popularity.POPULAR
            else -> Popularity.NORMAL
        }
    }

    fun onLike() {
        _likes.value = (_likes.value ?: 0) + 1
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class SimpleViewModelSolution : ViewModel() {


    val name: LiveData<String> =MutableLiveData("Ada")
    val lastName: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Lovelace")
    val likes: LiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)

    // popularity is exposed as LiveData using a Transformation instead of a @Bindable property.
    val popularity: LiveData<Popularity> = Transformations.map(likes) {           //The par 'likes' is OK
        when {
            it > 9 -> Popularity.STAR
            it > 4 -> Popularity.POPULAR
            else -> Popularity.NORMAL
        }
    }

    fun onLike() {
        var a=likes.value //It's OK        
        likes.value = (likes.value ?: 0) + 1  //Error
    }
}
```

**Image C**

[image]

Comment: You will be needed a `MutableLiveData` to change value instead `LiveData`. Always update the value on `MutableLiveData`

Comment: Thanks! but `val likes: LiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)` is a `MutableLiveData`

Comment: `likes` is not a `MutableLiveData`. `private val _likes = MutableLiveData<Int>()` then 
    `val likes: LiveData<Int> = _likes`. Always change `_likes ` which is `MutuableLiveData`. You cannot change `likes` which is `LiveData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise your `likes` object to MutableLiveData<> instead of LiveData<>
Change your code to:

```
val name: LiveData<String> =MutableLiveData("Ada")
val lastName: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Lovelace")
val likes: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)

// popularity is exposed as LiveData using a Transformation instead of a @Bindable property.
val popularity: LiveData<Popularity> = Transformations.map(likes) {           //The par 'likes' is OK
    when {
        it > 9 -> Popularity.STAR
        it > 4 -> Popularity.POPULAR
        else -> Popularity.NORMAL
    }
}

fun onLike() {
    var a = likes.value //It's OK
    likes.value = (likes.value ?: 0) + 1  //Now it'll work fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the **LiveData** directly but you've to use something called **MutableLiveData**, we can say that **LiveData** is **ImmutableLiveData** in some sense. *MutableLiveData* further provides you two more methods **postValue** and **setValue** which are explained over here in docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData
All you have to do

```
private val _likes: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
val likes : LiveData<Int>
get() = _likes
```

Above we Said now i am able to change LiveData but what value you wanna provide, for that you have do to

```
fun changeValue(newValue: Int) {
_likes.value = newValue
}
```

Inside your activity

```
vm.likes.observe(this, Observer{
//ui
}
```

And set the value whatever you want

```
vm.changeValue(1)
```